# Energy conservation in diamagnetic levitation

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, levitation

How do we account for conservation of energy in [diamagnetic levitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism#Levitation) when no external energy is required?

Comment: Why conservation of energy should be broken there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you expect that energy conservation should be broken.  Recall that it does not *necessarily* cost any energy to hold something in place.  A table does not expend any energy in keeping an object from falling to the floor.